# Botpress : How to reply with a dynamic multiple choice

Tags: bots, chatbot

I am trying to build a Botpress bot which gets replies for questions from backend. I am trying to inject a dynamic multiple choice question from backed as a reply to user. How can I do that? I couldn't find a way to do it in Botpress documentation or examples.

Answer (score 4):

Can you try this inside your src/actions.js file? I was using Single Choice Option to respond to user.

```
 getDataFromAPI: async (state, event) => {
      const endPoint = 'https://api.github.com/repos'
      try {
        let response = await instance.get(`${endPoint}`)
        console.log(response.data);
        await event.reply('#builtin_single-choice', JSON.parse(response.data))
      } catch (exception) {
        console.log(exception);
        await event.reply('#builtin_text', { text: `Failed to fetch data for this repo` })
      }
}
```

Response from the API call should be in JSON with the below format

```
{
  "text": "Offerings",
  "choices": [
    {
      "title": "Standard",
      "value": "standard"
    },
    {
      "title": "Custom",
      "value": "custom"
    },
    {
      "title": "Enterprise",
      "value": "enterprise"
    }
  ],
  "typing": true
}
```